# Why do we create a patch consisting of random numbers in TensorFlow, when building a convolutional neural network?

Tags: filtering, tensorflow, convolution

I'm going over the TensorFlow tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html) called 'Deep MNIST for Experts' (and I hope interpreting the word 'Expert' very loosely!)

I'm going over the part discussing how to set up the convolutions in a Convolutional Neural Network.

In a nutshell, they create a function for a weight:

```
def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)
```

which just outputs values from a truncated normal distribution. In my mind, I just see this as a matrix (ok, tensor) of random numbers.

To actually create a patch, they use this:

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
```

My question is this -- why is it smart to create a patch that consists of random values? Wouldn't it be better to choose a gigantic set of already existing patches? Like maybe a [Sobol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) patch, and a ton of others?

Am I getting this totally wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are suggesting to is to initialize the model initial weight parameters based on various available image processing patches that are commonly used to some success.

Initialization is a big research area in these Deep Neural architectures. Usual initialization strategies used in deep learning are designed to prevent the various problems associated with these models.

Some of the problems are:

Exploding gradients, which occur mainly with SGD (absent [atleast for text classification tasks] in the recent update measures like Adam, rmsprop etc.) refers to the problem where the gradient values get pushed further and further away, beyond the active region of the activation function, thereby preventing any training.

Vanishing gradients, which occur due to the non-linearity squashing the outputs to values close to zero, and thus preventing any update to occur in the weights present in all the layers after the layer where the gradient values become close to zero.

Various initialization strategies include:

- Xavier Initialization
- Mean Subtraction
- z-score Normalization
- 0.01 normal data around 0

Weight Initialization is best explained by:

http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/

http://deepdish.io/2015/02/24/network-initialization/

If you are more of a video person: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUtlrDbHhJM 37:00 - 51:00

Now I don't know much about the specifics of the particular Sobol patch you are referring to, or most of the others you have mentioned. But if they can conform to the specifications required of deep neural network initialization techniques, they can be used for initialization.